# C# Entity Foreign Key to List Array

Tags: c#, entity

I have a class `PromoCard` and `List<PromoCard> PromoCards`. Is it possible to map element of List array in Entity Model?

This is my List:

```
public static List<PromoCard> PromoCards = new List<PromoCard>
{
    new PromoCard()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Crystal = 4500,
        Price = 100
    },
    new PromoCard()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Crystal = 24000,
        Price = 500
    },
    new PromoCard()
    {
        Id = 3,
        Crystal = 50000,
        Price = 1000
    },
};

public class PromoCard
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Crystal { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my model:

```
public class BonusCard
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User_id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public int PromoCard_id { get; set; }
    // is there way to link 
    [ForeignKey("PromoCard_id")]
    public virtual PromoCard PromoCard { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Each table in the database is a list object at the root of Entity.  So you have dbContext that has List<BonusCard>.  So you can create new table in database that is PromoCard with three columns Id, Crystal, and Price.  So you can simply manually add the new table into the database and then Refresh the mapping from database to c# which will create the new class PromoCard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to was change the getter of `PromoCard` property and put NotMapped Annotation on it

```
public class BonusCard
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User_id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
    public DateTime UsageDate { get; set; } = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
    public int? Player_id { get; set; } = null;
    [ForeignKey("Player_id")]
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public int PromoCard_id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public  PromoCard PromoCard { get { return PromoCards[PromoCard_id]; } set { } }
}
```